# How to manually call MediaWiki to convert wiki text to HTML?

Tags: php, html, mediawiki, wikitext

I have a MediaWiki installation and I'm writing a custom script that reads some database entries and produces a custom output for client.

However, the text are in wiki format, and I need to convert them to HTML. Is there some PHP API I could call -- well there must be, but what and how exactly?

What files to include and what to call?

Comment: did you have a look at [mediawiki2html](http://code.google.com/p/gwtwiki/wiki/Mediawiki2HTML) ?

Comment: I'm using PHP just like the MediaWiki itself. The library seems to be for Java.

Comment: right - i thought that was a black box to which you gave the page name for example and it generates the html page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the global object [`$wgParser`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgParser) to do this:

```
<?php

require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/WebStart.php');

$output = $wgParser->parse(
    "some ''wikitext''",
    Title::newFromText('Some page title'),
    new ParserOptions());
echo $output->getText();

?>
```

Although I have no idea whether doing it this way is a good practice, or whether there is some better way.

Comment: This works otherwise great, but I want to get rid of images -- I am doing this for "an offline print" and we don't want images, is there a way to configure it or should I try to `preg_replace()` them off?

Comment: Can't you hide them using CSS? I think that would be a clean solution. [I would be very careful with using regular expressions to process HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/41071)

Answer (score 2):

All I found is [dumpHTML.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDumpHTML) that will dump all your mediawiki ; or may be better [API:Parser wiki text](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext) which tells :

> If you are interested in simply getting the rendered content of a
>   page, you can bypass the api and simply add action=render to your url,
>   like so: /w/index.php?title=API:Parsing_wikitext&action=render

Once you add action=render it seems you can get the html page ; dont you think ?

hope this could help.

regards.

Comment: It's a shame I have to call an URL, because that can't be very fast for a large wiki...

Comment: i agree :/ i just give you what seems to be the possible answer from the existing resources - this last suggestion should be enough for some page ; but if you need it for the complete wiki dumpHTML may be do the trick ?